# How can I make a prototype function to all my object properties?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have an object of functions and I like to prototype another function to all of these properties.

Example:

```
var test = function(num) {
  return num * num / (num/4);
}

var obj = {
  item1: item1, //this is a function already setted.
  item2: item2, //this is a function already setted.
  item3: item3 //this is a function already setted
}
```

What I want is something like: `obj.item1().test()` without setting `this.test` inside each function.

Comment: Show us `item1`, `item2` and `item3` as well.

Comment: It's just an example, it can be `var itemX = function(val) {this.num = val; return this.num};`

Comment: the only prototype they share is `Function.prototype`; do you want to edit that?

Comment: Not really. Just for this object

Comment: then you need to iteratate and define each method for each property, which isn't very fun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `test` function

```
return num * num / (num/4);
```

is exactly equivalent to `num * 4` as far as I can see.

Anyway, the example `itemX` given in your comment returns a number. The only way to be able to call the function `test` on a number is to add it to the `Number` prototype, which some people would say is a bad idea:

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'test', { value: function () {
    return this * this / (this/4);
});
```

If you want to be able to chain `test` from the result of the call to `obj.itemX`, then the latter needs to return `this`, not `this.num`:

```
var itemX = function(val) {this.num = val; return this};
```

Now you just need to place a modified version of `test` once on `obj`:

```
var obj = {
  item1: item1, //this is a function already set.
  item2: item2, //this is a function already set.
  item3: item3, //this is a function already set.

  test: function() { return test(this.num); }
};

> obj.item1(22).test()
< 88
```

> How can I make a prototype function to all my object properties?

If you are referring to `test`, this is not a prototype function. It's just a plain old method on an object. To add it, just add it on the object, as done above.

Comment: Oh, yeah, my mistake. I wrote that function from my phone and sleepy. But its just for example. Thanks

P.s: Object.defineProperty is missing a `}` before closing function.